# RUC Ecuadorian Validator

Tags: typescript, validation

SO I want to update an Identification Card (IC or ID) validator to Single Taxpayer Registry(STR or RUC on Spanish) validator

The process for validation is as follows:

- The Ecuadorian ID is formed by the first two digits that correspond to the province where it was issued, therefore, the first two digits will not be greater than 24 nor less than 0.
- The third digit is a number less than 6 (0,1,2,3,4,5).
- The next ones up to the ninth digit are a consecutive number.
- The tenth is the check digit.
  The coefficients used to verify the tenth digit of the ID, using "Module 10".
  Coefficients = 2.1.2.1.2.1.2.1.2
  [image]

```
function validarCedula(cedula: string) {
  if (cedula.length === 10) {
    const digitoRegion = cedula.substring(0, 2);
    if (digitoRegion >= String(1) && digitoRegion <= String(24)) {
      const ultimoDigito = Number(cedula.substring(9, 10));
      const pares = Number(cedula.substring(1, 2)) + Number(cedula.substring(3, 4)) + Number(cedula.substring(5, 6)) + Number(cedula.substring(7, 8));
      let numeroUno: any = cedula.substring(0, 1);
      numeroUno = (numeroUno * 2);
      if (numeroUno > 9) {
        numeroUno = (numeroUno - 9);
      }
      let numeroTres: any = cedula.substring(2, 3);
      numeroTres = (numeroTres * 2);
      if (numeroTres > 9) {
        numeroTres = (numeroTres - 9);
      }
      let numeroCinco: any = cedula.substring(4, 5);
      numeroCinco = (numeroCinco * 2);
      if (numeroCinco > 9) {
        numeroCinco = (numeroCinco - 9);
      }
      let numeroSiete: any = cedula.substring(6, 7);
      numeroSiete = (numeroSiete * 2);
      if (numeroSiete > 9) {
        numeroSiete = (numeroSiete - 9);
      }
      let numeroNueve: any = cedula.substring(8, 9);
      numeroNueve = (numeroNueve * 2);
      if (numeroNueve > 9) {
        numeroNueve = (numeroNueve - 9);
      }
      const impares = numeroUno + numeroTres + numeroCinco + numeroSiete + numeroNueve;
      const sumaTotal = (pares + impares);
      const primerDigitoSuma = String(sumaTotal).substring(0, 1);
      const decena = (Number(primerDigitoSuma) + 1) * 10;
      let digitoValidador = decena - sumaTotal;
      if (digitoValidador === 10) {
        digitoValidador = 0;
      }
      if (digitoValidador === ultimoDigito) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }

}
```

But in the case of the STR(RUC on Spanish) which requires
The ruc will be 13 digits, no letters, no special characters.

- The third digit will be 6 or 9 depending on the type of person.
- The last three digits are 001,002,003 etc., depending on the number of additional establishments.
- The validation of the Identity Card passes an algorithm "Module 11". The number is divided into 13 parts, the first 9 are the number itself, 10 is the self-checking digit for legal entities and position 9 is the self-checking digit for public institutions, and the remaining 3 indicate whether it is the main or establishment additional.
- The first 2 positions correspond to the province where it was issued, so the first two numbers will not be greater than 22 nor less than 1.
- The last 3 digits cannot be 000 for legal entities and the last digits cannot be 0000 for public institutions, since they will always have at least one main one.
- The coefficients used to verify the tenth digit of the ID, using the algorithm "Module 11".

Exceptions:

- If the remainder is 0, it is a check digit 0.

[image]

[image]

which remains me on to optimize the ID code  or reuse got no idea and looking for many options while trying to solve it

Comment: This Ecuador RUC is similar (but not equal) to the RUC in Paraguay. I wrote [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61656819/9225671) about Paraguays RUC that might help you with some pointers.